# Reactive Web Flux Security not extracting roles from JWT token

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot 3.2, Spring Security 6

This is a Spring Cloud Gateway which I have implemented as a OAuth2 Resource Server which also has actuator endpoints. I am attempting to use the JWT roles to restrict access to the actuator endpoints. I have successfully done this in another microservice in the non-reactive stack. However, the Gateway doesn't support starter-web. I can't figure out the equivalent JWT Converter in the reactive stack.

The EnableWebFluxSecurity ServerHttpSecurity is being set to allow access to actuator endpoints based on JWT roles from the jwt token. However, when debugging the AbstractAuthenticationToken only has "SCOPE_" granted authorities. Should also have extracted the JWT User Roles.

pom:

```
        <!--#### SECURITY ###-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--#### REST ###-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Props:

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
    web-application-type: reactive
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: "http://localhost:${env.idp-port}/realms/osint-realm"
          jwk-set-uri: ${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/certs

jwt:
  token:
    converter:
      resource-id: osint-keycloak-client
      principal-attribute: preferred_username
```

Server Filter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class WebFluxSecurityConfig {

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String appName;

    private final CustomJwtTokenConverter customJwtTokenConverter;

    public WebFluxSecurityConfig(TokenConverterProperties tokenConverterProperties) {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        this.customJwtTokenConverter = new CustomJwtTokenConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter, tokenConverterProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity) {
        serverHttpSecurity
            .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
            .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable)
            .authorizeExchange(exchange ->  {
                exchange.pathMatchers("/eureka/**").permitAll();
                exchange.pathMatchers("/" + appName + "/actuator/**").hasRole("actuator");
                exchange.anyExchange().authenticated();
            })
            //This is only pulling scopes not roles?
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return serverHttpSecurity.build();
    }
```

I believe the issue is the JWT Customizer.withDefaults. I think that this is giving me the Anonymous Authority with SCOPE_profile, SCOPE_email which are not on the provided JWT Token

I have attempted to follow [Spring Security 6.1.4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html) However, the snippets are pretty vague for creating a custom JWT Converter.

This is my attempt at a Customer JWT Converter

```
public class CustomJwtTokenConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ACCESS = "resource_access";
    private static final String ROLES = "roles";
    protected static final String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";
    private final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;
    private final TokenConverterProperties properties;

    public CustomJwtTokenConverter(
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter,
        TokenConverterProperties properties) {
        this.jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(@NonNull Jwt jwt) {
        List<Collection<String>> roleResources = Optional.of(jwt)
            .map(token -> token.getClaimAsMap(RESOURCE_ACCESS))
            .map(claimMap -> (Map<String, Object>) claimMap.get(properties.getResourceId()))
            .map(resourceData -> (Collection<String>) resourceData.get(ROLES))
            .stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> simpleGrantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        roleResources.forEach(role -> role.forEach(roleValue -> simpleGrantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_PREFIX + roleValue))));

        Stream<SimpleGrantedAuthority> accesses = simpleGrantedAuthorities.stream().distinct();

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Stream
            .concat(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt).stream(), accesses)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        String principalClaimName = properties.getPrincipalAttribute()
            .map(jwt::getClaimAsString)
            .orElse(jwt.getClaimAsString(JwtClaimNames.SUB));

        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities, principalClaimName);
    }
}
```

However, this is providing a CustomerJwtTokenConverter not a Converter in filter:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity) {
        serverHttpSecurity
            .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
            .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable)
            .authorizeExchange(exchange ->  {
                exchange.pathMatchers("/eureka/**").permitAll();
                exchange.pathMatchers("/" + appName + "/actuator/**").hasRole("actuator");
                exchange.anyExchange().authenticated();
            })
            //This is only pulling scopes not roles?
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
//                .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
                .jwt(jwtSpec -> jwtSpec.jwtAuthenticationConverter(this.customJwtTokenConverter)));
        return serverHttpSecurity.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your converter is a synchronized converter (for servlets), not a reactive one.

The interface to implement is `Converter<Jwt, ? extends Mono<? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken>>`, not `Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>`.

##### Slightly easier than implementing the authentication converter by yourself

You can probably use `ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter` implementation provided by Spring security. This makes things easier as such a bean would be automatically picked by Spring Boot when you use `http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))`.

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
static class KeycloakClientAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Flux<GrantedAuthority>> {
    private final TokenConverterProperties properties;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Flux<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt source) {
        final var resourceAccess = (Map<String, Object>) source.getClaims().getOrDefault("resource_access", Map.of());
        final var clientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.getOrDefault(properties.getResourceId(), Map.of());
        final var roles = (List<String>) clientAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());
        return Flux.fromStream(roles.stream())
                .map(r -> "ROLE_%s".formatted(r))
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .map(GrantedAuthority.class::cast);
    }
}

@Bean
ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter(Converter<Jwt, Flux<GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesConverter) {
    final var authenticationConverter = new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter();
    authenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(authoritiesConverter);
    authenticationConverter.setPrincipalClaimName(StandardClaimNames.PREFERRED_USERNAME);
    return authenticationConverter;
}
```

##### Solution with almost no Java conf

I maintain an [additional Spring Boot starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) which allows to define almost all OAuth2 config in application properties:

- JSON path(s) for the claim(s) to use as source for authorities with basic transformation such as adding `ROLE_` prefix or forcing lower / upper case (for each path)
- JSON path to the claim to use as username (useful when this claim is nested like the custom claims with Auth0)
- path matchers for resources accessible to anonymous (`/eureka/**` in your conf)
- a few other things like CORS config

All you'd have to write as Java code would be your access control rules. Your config would probably look something like that:

```xml
<!-- add this to spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

```yaml
# you can remove spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.* properties
# as well as jwt.* ones
com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: http://localhost:${env.idp-port}/realms/osint-realm
          authorities:
          - path: $.resource_access.osint-keycloak-client.roles
            prefix: ROLE_
          username-claim: preferred_username
        resourceserver:
          permit-all:
          - /eureka/**
```

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConf {
    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String appName;
    
    @Bean
    ResourceServerAuthorizeExchangeSpecPostProcessor authorizeRequests() {
        return (ServerHttpSecurity.AuthorizeExchangeSpec spec) -> {
            // permitAll to /eureka/** is managed in properties
            spec.pathMatchers("/%s/actuator/**".formatted(appName)).hasRole("actuator");
            spec.anyExchange().authenticated();
            return spec;
        };
    }

    // Security(Web)FilterChain(s) based on application properties is already provided
}
```

This starter supports client and resource server configuration: it creates two distinct security filter-chains if you provide the conf for the two and have both `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` on the classpath. This means that you can configure your gateway as BFF (with `TokenRelay` filter and OAuth2 login, which require client configuration with sessions) and have some endpoints configured as stateless resource server (like your Eureka and actuator endpoints).

It also supports servlet and reactive applications (it adapts depending on what is on the classpath).

Comment: Thanks @ch4mp for taking the time to look at this and the thorough response. Funny thing is I came across your repo yesterday while adding tests to one of the non-reactive microservices. My thought was to add resource and client to the Gateway with no OIDC since for now it is all machine to machine. When we stand up an Operational Dashboard it will probably authenticate directly to IDP and forward the token through the gateway.

Comment: Given my use case, I assume then I would be following https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/reactive-resource-server and https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/reactive-client independently or is there a way to use spring-addons-starter-oidc and turn off any logon forwarding?

Comment: In my opinion, OAuth2 security makes sense on a Gateway, only when it is used as BFF for SPA or mobile app (the security filter-chain should contain a `securityMatcher` to limit it to these requests). REST APIs should always be configured as resource server (even behind a Gateway) and Spring MVC apps should be OAuth2 clients (with login). Of cours, when the gateway is a REST API (like actuator endpoints in your question), then it should have a resource server filter-chain for this endpoints.

Comment: My BFF tutorial configures two distinct filter-chains on the gateway: an OAuth2 client one (with login) for routes with `TokenRelay` filter and an OAuth2 resource server one for public resources (this 2nd filter-chain could secure protected REST resources like some actuator endpoints, even if I don't do it in this tutorial).

Comment: I successfully added reactive oauth to another microservice following bff-c4 repo. Is there a way to add custom 401/403 handlers? Adding the accessDeniedHandler from https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/reactive-resource-server/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/tutorials/WebSecurityConfig.java#L109 seemed to break the chain and return 200

Comment: I also don't see any M2M solutions as a client samples. They all seem to be SPA with log on pages.

Comment: The access denied handler you refer to sets [either 401 or 403 as response status](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/139339c672fb57611bae5a20b0be27f698b253f3/samples/tutorials/reactive-resource-server/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/tutorials/WebSecurityConfig.java#L112) but never 200, so your error comes from elsewhere.

Comment: There is M2M in the `resource-server_with_ui`: [the MVC controller uses a `@FeignClient` to query the REST API](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/139339c672fb57611bae5a20b0be27f698b253f3/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/tutorials/ui/UiController.java#L69)